# Karate API function/keyword to substitute JSON placeholder key with argument passed

Tags: karate

In Webservice Testing using Karate API, how do I substitute JSON key with a value I defined in Background?

**Background:** I am hitting a REST API endpoint through Karate API. This returns me a deep nested JSON. Once I get response, I need to evaluate if response contains my parameter as key and if key's value is not null. Below is my code

```
Background:
* def execParam = 'ArgumentProvided'

@MyTestCase
Given url myUrl + '/' + execParam
When method get
Then status 200
And match response.subElement contains {execParam : '#notnull'}
```

With above code, assertions fail with error

`expected: {execParam:'#notnull'}, reason: actual value does not contain expected`

My expectation is for code to assert `{'ArgumentProvided':'#notnull'}`. Code currently asserts `{execParam:'#notnull'}`

I tried to replace `execParam` with `#execParam`, `$.execParam` and `#[$.execParam]` and none of these substitute the value. So need help substituting the JSON key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this interesting use case, you can construct the expected JSON on the fly like this:

```
* def execParam = 'ArgumentProvided'
* def response = { subElement: { ArgumentProvided: 'foo' } }
* def expected = {}
* expected[execParam] = '#notnull'
* match expected == { ArgumentProvided: '#notnull' }
* match response.subElement contains expected
```